# VB.NET: How to find a word after a specific word in a line and store it

Tags: vb.net

I have a continuous string of words coming from a machine to hyper terminal of my system, for which I am using USB to serial cable. I want to find some of the values which comes after a specific word in that string and then store it.

I used threads and splitting concepts to do it but as per the requirement and operation of the machine  it will not work properly in the runtime.

The values which I want to capture comes from a specific word. I want to skip that words and just store the values. How to do it?

I have given the example of that string below:

```
MEAN 49  50
SD   500 10
MIN  100 5
MAX  50  45.56
```

In this I just want to store the values e.g. `49` and `50`, then discard `MEAN`. Then discard `SD` and store `500` and `10` and so on.

Comment: You can use `instr` to find the start of a string within another string. Using that and the length of the string you are looking for you can find the numerical values. I would suggest comma delimiting the string if you can then you can search for commas as reference points

Comment: You could use [Regex.Match(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) and filter for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StreamReader` object to read the stream one line at a time.  Then, you can easily parse the line using the `String.Split` method.  I would recommend creating one or more classes that represent the data being read, like this:

```
Public Class LineData
    Public Property Label As String
    Public Property Value1 As Decimal
    Public Property Value2 As Decimal
End Class

Public Function ReadNextLine(stream As Stream) As LineData
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
    Dim data As LineData = Nothing
    If line IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim words() As String = line.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If words.Length = 3 Then
            data = New LineData()
            data.Label = words(0)
            data.Value1 = Decimal.Parse(words(1))
            data.Value2 = Decimal.Parse(words(2))
        End If
    End If
    Return Data
End Function
```

Note, this is a very simple example based on the example data you provided.  If different lines have different numbers of numeric parameters, that will further complicate the logic.  In my example, the method returns `Nothing` if no data can be read.  Also, the method will throw an exception if the last two words in the line are not numeric.  Therefore, you would need to wrap it in some additional exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for. Although personally I'd create a class which stores the type(mean, median etc), firstvalue and secondvalue.

By the sounds of it though, all you want it to do is dump the values into some sort of storage, therefore this will suffice.

```
Dim Values as New List(Of Decimal)

'Use a streamreader to read each line of text
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(*your text source*)
'Read the line 
Dim linetext as string = reader.ReadLine
Dim myValue as decimal
'Split the line
Dim splitText() = linetext.Split(" ")
'Analyze each section of the line, if its possible to parse the value as a decimal then add it to the list of values to be stored.
For Each txt in splitText
If Decimal.TryParse(txt, myValue) then Values.Add(myValue)
Next
End Using
```